# Table conversion in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table example input :

```
Energy1              Energy2 
-966.463549649       -966.463549649
-966.463608088       -966.463585840
```

So I need a script for summing the two energies E1 and E2 and then convert with a factor *627.51 (hartree in kcal/mol) and at the end truncate the number with 4 digits.

I never attempted this with Python.  I've always written this in Julia, but I think it should be simple.
Do you know how I can find an example of reading the table and then doing operations with the numbers in it?

something like:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.loadtxt('table.tab')
print(data[?:,?].sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this if you convert the table to a csv file. You add the columns directly then use the apply function with lambda to multiply each of the elements by the conversion factor. To truncate to 4 digits, you can change pandas global settings to display the format as 1 digit + 3 decimal in scientific notation.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.3E}'.format)
df['Sum Energies'] = (df['Energy1'] + df['Energy2']).apply(lambda x: x*627.51)

print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
     Energy1    Energy2  Sum Energies
0 -9.665E+02 -9.665E+02    -1.213E+06
1 -9.665E+02 -9.665E+02    -1.213E+06
```

Comment: How I can install this pandas module in python3?

Comment: @Fred open terminal, type 'pip3 install pandas'